# Path / Location of Cocos2d-x UserDefault data in IOS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cocos2d-x

I am tasked to migrate an IOS game made with Cocos2d-x into Unity. One of the issues I have is that I don't know where Cocos2d-x writes the user's saved data. The Unity version of the app needs to access that data so that the user doesn't lose their progress.

The Cocos2d-x application saves it's data using something like this: `userDefault->setIntegerForKey("coins", 35);`

Would anybody know what path/location that user's saved data is stored? Are there ways I can find that out? I've already tried to view it on xcode via `Window > Devices and Simulators > Installed Apps` but the app isn't listed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From Unity you may try to use `PlayerPrefs` which is basically a wrapper around iOS NSUserDefaults. Does `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins")` returns the value saved from cocos2d-x?

Comment: @Dalmas it actually worked! thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d-x v4:

```
// write string
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:value.c_str()] forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:pKey]];

// read string
NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:pKey]];

// read integer
NSNumber *value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:pKey]];
```

Before V 2.1.2 the info was stored in UserDefault.xml

```
#define XML_FILE_NAME "UserDefault.xml"

#ifdef KEEP_COMPATABILITY
    if (! _isFilePathInitialized)
    {
        // xml file is stored in cache directory before 2.1.2
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        _filePath = [documentsDirectory UTF8String];
        _filePath.append("/");

       _filePath +=  XML_FILE_NAME;
      _isFilePathInitialized = true;
    }
#endif
```